# Send keys to unfocused window

Tags: c#, bots

im frustrated, i´ve been trying almost for 2 weeks to make a bot for a game that runs on the background on my PC.
Basically i want a bot that presses 1 and TAB every 5 seconds on a game that is in the background and doesnt have focus. I already spoke with a guy that achieved it but he said that as it wasnt easy he wouldnt tell me how he did it, he only said that it has to do with the process pipe and that i should focus on the events that activate a window.
And he sent me this link:
https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Constants.WM.

Any help would be appreciated.

This is my latest try that worked in the background but only for notepad:

```
static class Program
{
    const UInt32 WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    const UInt32 WM_KEYUP = 0x0101;
    const int VK_D1 = 0x0031;
    


    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        while (true)
        {

            IntPtr hwnd = (IntPtr)1517968;
            PostMessage(hwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_D1, 0);
            Console.WriteLine(hwnd);
            PostMessage(hwnd, WM_KEYUP, VK_D1, 0);

            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what makes you think 1517968 is correct? are you getting the handle some other way?

Comment: Just a heads up -- This dude who's giving you a hard time... he didn't invent this type of program. This type of stuff has been around for ages. Here's something I found that even works in C# https://github.com/EasyAsABC123/Keyboard/

Comment: that handle is the handle of notepad and it worked, i was just debugging it to see if it worked with it

Comment: And if i remember correctly, Notepad.exe specifically can not accept keyboard input if it's not focused. It's programmed to act like that. Try it on Notepad++.